# How to send a generated excel file as an email attachment in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing a MVC project, one of the pages, generates a DataTable which dynamically changes. I am supposed to do two functionalities,

1)generate an excel file and make it downloadable for end user - I have a successfully done it.

2) Email the excel attachment to the end user. - I thought it should be a easy one, but it looks complicated. I do not want to save the excel temporarily somewhere in the server, and attach it in email. due to security constraints. (the user will just click on email button and it should reach his email)

Here is my code, It doesnot do anything rather than sending me an empty excel file.

```
            public void EmailCurrMonthSummary()
                    {
                        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
                        MonthEndSummary mes = new MonthEndSummary();
                        DataTable tempTable = new DataTable();
                        mes.MonthEndSummaryTable = da.GetCurrMonthSummary(); //returns a DataTable                    

                        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                        mail.To.Add("User@xxx.com");
                        mail.From = new MailAddress("Sender@xxx.com");
                        mail.Body = "Hello World";
                        mail.Subject = "Month End Status";
            System.IO.MemoryStream str = DataToExcel(mes.MonthEndSummaryTable,"MonthEndSummary.xls");

            Attachment at = new Attachment(str, "MonthEndSummary.xls");

                        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                        SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                        smtp.Send(mail);
                    }


 public System.IO.MemoryStream DataToExcel(DataTable dt, string filename)
        {
            //StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter();
            System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
                dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
                dgGrid.DataBind();
                dgGrid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
                //Get the HTML for the control.
                dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
                //Write the HTML back to the browser.
                //Response.ContentType = application/vnd.ms-excel;
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
                Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

            }
            System.IO.MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
            System.Text.Encoding Enc = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
            byte[] mBArray = Enc.GetBytes(tw.ToString());
            s = new MemoryStream(mBArray, false);

            //return Content(tw.ToString(), "application/ms-excel");
            return s;
        }
```

Can some one help me how to send the excel generated in DataToExcel function ?

Comment: What issue u are facing ?

Comment: `mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(_excelStream,_fileName))`

Comment: Generated excel is not attaching. Not sure if that was the right thing to do

Comment: Try with my code and let me know

Comment: What should be the _fileName ? How do i Pass the contentresult that is created?

Comment: You have to call this way

 bool isMailSent = Utility.SendMail(string.Empty, mailTo, string.Empty, string.Empty, subject, mailMessage, true, string.Empty, Resource.EmailFrom);

Answer (score 2):

After a little tweaking, The below code worked fine for me.

```
            public void EmailCurrMonthSummary()
                    {
                        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
                        MonthEndSummary mes = new MonthEndSummary();
                        DataTable tempTable = new DataTable();
                        mes.MonthEndSummaryTable = da.GetCurrMonthSummary(); //returns a DataTable                    

                        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                        mail.To.Add("User@xxx.com");
                        mail.From = new MailAddress("Sender@xxx.com");
                        mail.Body = "Hello World";
                        mail.Subject = "Month End Status";
System.IO.MemoryStream str = DataToExcel(mes.MonthEndSummaryTable);

            Attachment at = new Attachment(str, "MonthEndSummary.xls");
            mail.Attachments.Add(at);    

                        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                        SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                        smtp.Send(mail);
                    }


 public System.IO.MemoryStream DataToExcel(DataTable dt)
        {
            //StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter();
            System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
                dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
                dgGrid.DataBind();
                dgGrid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
                //Get the HTML for the control.
                dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
                //Write the HTML back to the browser.
                //Response.ContentType = application/vnd.ms-excel;
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

            }
            System.IO.MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
            System.Text.Encoding Enc = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
            byte[] mBArray = Enc.GetBytes(tw.ToString());
            s = new MemoryStream(mBArray, false);

            return s;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static void SetSmtpDetails()
     {
        ConfigurationModel smtpConfig = GetConfiguration(ConfigurationKey.SMTPServer.ToString());
        string smtpServerValue = smtpConfig.Value;

        ConfigurationModel smtpUserConfig = GetConfiguration(ConfigurationKey.SMTPUser.ToString());
        string smtpUserValue = smtpUserConfig.Value;

        ConfigurationModel smtpPasswordConfig = GetConfiguration(ConfigurationKey.SMTPPassword.ToString());
        string smtpPAsswordValue = smtpPasswordConfig.Value;

        ConfigurationModel smtpSslConfig = GetConfiguration(ConfigurationKey.EnableSsl.ToString());
        string smtpEnableSSl = smtpSslConfig.Value;

        ConfigurationModel portConfig = GetConfiguration(ConfigurationKey.Port.ToString());

        SmtpServer = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(smtpServerValue) ? Convert.ToString(smtpServerValue) : SmtpServer;
        SmtpUser = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(smtpUserValue) ? Convert.ToString(smtpUserValue) : SmtpUser;
        SmtpPassword = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(smtpPAsswordValue) ? Convert.ToString(smtpPAsswordValue) : SmtpPassword;
        EnableSsl = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(smtpEnableSSl) ? Convert.ToBoolean(smtpEnableSSl) : EnableSsl;
        Port = Convert.ToInt32(portConfig.Value);
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
    }


public static bool SendMail(string fromAddress, string toAddress, string ccAddress, string bccAddress, string subject, string bodyMessage, bool isBodyHtml, string fileName, string fromName)
    {
        SetSmtpDetails();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromAddress))
        {
            fromAddress = SmtpUser;
        }
        try
        {
            var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            if (ccAddress != null && ccAddress.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                mailMessage.CC.Add(ccAddress);
            }

            if (bccAddress != null && bccAddress.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                mailMessage.Bcc.Add(bccAddress);
            }

            mailMessage.To.Add(toAddress);
            if (fromAddress != null && fromAddress.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                if (fromName != null && fromName.Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress, fromName);
                }
                else
                {
                    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
                }
            }

            subject = subject.Replace('\r', ' ').Replace('\n', ' ');
            bodyMessage = bodyMessage.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");

            mailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            mailMessage.Body = bodyMessage;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
            mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;

            if (fileName != null && fileName.Trim().Length > 0 && File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileName));
            }

            var client = new SmtpClient();
            try
            {
                client.Host = SmtpServer;
                client.Port = Port;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, SmtpPassword);
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.EnableSsl = EnableSsl;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
                            client.SendAsync(mailMessage, Tuple.Create(client, mailMessage)));

            }
            catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
            {
                if (smtpEx.Message.Contains("secure connection"))
                {
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.Send(mailMessage);
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Error occured while sending Email  : From Address: {0} \r\n - ToAddress : {1} \r\n ", fromAddress, toAddress), ex);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I do not want to save the file somewhere in the server.  Your code looks like you are sending attachment of an existing file.

Comment: No this solution save file in your local path not on server

Hope it is clear

Comment: As I said, I want to use excel generated in DataToExcel function.